# Notepad++ - Display Word Count in Status Bar

Tags: notepad++, word-count

Notepad++ shows the number of characters and lines in the status bar as a default; if I double click it, it brings up the Summary dialog which shows the word count.

Can I display the word count as a default at the status bar?

Answer (score 2):

Unfurtuanlly there is no way to add this to the Status Bar.

(maybe if enough people will request it [[here](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/1136) is already a request for it on their GitHub project] they'll add it...)